# Why is it giving runtime error on codeforces for python?

Tags: python

So I am very new to code and have learnt the basics of python. I am testing out my skills on codeforces by first solving some of their easier problems. I am trying to do 158A on codeforces. I think I have got it because it passed a few tests I assigned. So, I tried submitting it and it told me something about a runtime error. I don't really know what it is so I would like it if someone could tell me what it is and how to fix it in my code. Here is the link to the problem: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/158/A

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
b = []
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input())
    b.append(a)
c = 0
for i in b:
    if i >= b[k]:
        c = c+1
    else:
        pass
print(c)
```

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the actual error? (word for word)

Comment: it says "runtime error on trial 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you are given is "8 5" and "10 9 8 7 7 7 5 5". That doesn't mean you are given "8" and "5" as two different inputs. It means you have a very long string that contains numbers separated by spaces. You should turn these into a list.

```
a = input()

n = int(a.split(" ")[0])
k = int(a.split(" ")[1])
```

`a` should equal "8 5". We then turn the string into a list using `a.split(" ")`. This will produce `["8", "5"]`.

Comment: Or `n, k = map(int, input().split(' '))`.

Comment: @Prathmesh could it be that the input is in a file, such as "input.txt" or "problem.in"?

Comment: what do you mean? I am sorry I am very new to this but I think it's a normal input. I think we need to find a way to make those 10 9 8 7 7 7 5 5 into a single input and put it into a list so i can fetch the 5th value. I think that is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

In the problem `158A` the expected input are:
**1.** Two numbers (int) separated by a single space, where *1 ≤ k ≤ n ≤ 50*
**2.** *n* space-separated integers, where *ai ≥ ai + 1* 

There is also a condition: Scores MUST be positive (*score>0*) so you can advance
This is all you need, I tested it and I got the expected output everytime

```
a = input("Input n and k: ")
n = int(a.split(" ")[0])
k = int(a.split(" ")[1])
b = input("Input  n scores: ")

willAdvance = 0
scores = b.split()
print(scores)
for element in scores:
    if int(element) >= int(scores[k-1]) and int(scores[k-1]) > 0:
        willAdvance += 1

print(willAdvance)
```

### TEST

Input:

```
8 5
10 9 8 7 7 7 5 5
```

Output:

```
6
```

Input:

```
4 6
0 0 0 0
```

Output:

```
0
```